# Knowing that they are independence events, what's P(A) or P(B)?

Tags: probability

The question is:

Two events $A$ and $B$ independent with each other, $P(A)=0.16$ and $P(B)=0.5$. What's the probability of happening the event $A$ or $B$?

First of all what the question is asking is: $P(A\cup B) = ?$

I've think a lot about it, and I found an relevant relation knowing that both events $A$ and $B$ are independent.
This is the relation: $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.

But I don't know how to relate this information with the question.

Comment: Probablity of event A OR event B happening is UNION... Probability of event A AND event B happening is INTERSECTION

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. The missing piece of information you need is the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability): $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate!